# How to get a reverse complement of a sequence in python

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a program, that reverses the inputed sequence and then asks the user to enter another sequence, until the user enters a sequence that does not contain A,T,G,C and provides a error message. My code below gives my the reverse complement, but does not prompt the user to enter another sequence, any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is my code:

```
def revcomp(s, reverse, complement):
    bases = 'ATGCTACG'
    complement_dict = {bases[i]:bases[i+4] for i in range(4)}
    if reverse:
       dna = reversed(dna)
       result_as_list = None
    if complement:
       result_as_list = [complement_dict[base] for base in dna]
    else:
       result_as_list = [base for base in dna]
       return ''.join(result_as_list)

s = input("enter sequence")
variable = revcomp(s, reverse, complement)
print("Reverse comp", variable)
```

Comment: You don't define reverse complement. You also never use the `sequence` variable of your `input`

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive. Please indent the code you provided to match the code in your editor.

Comment: Did you mean `def revcomp(dna, reverse, complement):`?

Comment: Yes, def revcomp(dna, reverse, complement):